# will a newly created and pushed local branch will clash if there is alreay a branch with the same name in the github?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have question about Git. here is the scenario
say I have created a local branch and pushed it to the origin master(github)(not merged just pushed and pull request created. Then deleted the local branch.

Now if I create another local branch with the same name, commit and push it to the origin master on github what will happen ?

Will be a new branch created on github or this commit will update the previously created pull request ?

I hope my question is clear enough to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No. I am working in a very sensitive project. My manager will not like if it create another branch. So I would like to be sure about the outcome before I try it ?

Comment: You could trivially set up a new Github repo to run experiments on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you will receive an error like:

```
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo_url>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

Because the new branch will have changes that are not build based on the old branch.

Also, note that because git is a distributed version control system you don't need to test your changes using the real repo. You can always create multiple test repositories on your local machine (that are not related to the real ones) and clone them to simulate the process.